# Web long polling using parse.com

Tags: web, parse-platform, polling

My problem is that I am building a app using parse (http://parse.com) and also a website to support it but didn't find a solution to add the "instant messaging" feature to web (Like facebook messaging)

The app (IOS) has a messaging feature that uses push notifications and works just fine.

What can I use for the web part to emulate that? Is it possible to use long polling somehow? What options are available?

I have tried using cloud code but was unsuccessful